# Want to remove duplicated rows unless NA value exists in columns

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, conditional-statements, distinct

I have a data table with 4 columns: ID, Name, Rate1, Rate2.

I want to remove duplicates where ID, Rate1, and Rate 2 are the same, ***but***  if they are both NA, I would like to keep both rows.

Basically, I want to conditionally remove duplicates, but only if the conditions != NA.

For example, I would like this:

```
ID   Name   Rate1    Rate2
1    Xyz    1        2
1    Abc    1        2
2    Def    NA       NA
2    Lmn    NA       NA
3    Hij    3        5
3    Qrs    3        7
```

to become this:

```
ID   Name   Rate1    Rate2
1    Xyz    1        2
2    Def    NA       NA
2    Lmn    NA       NA
3    Hij    3        5
3    Qrs    3        7
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I know it's possible to just take a subset of the data table where the Rates are NA, then remove duplicates on what's left, then add the NA rows back in - but, I would rather avoid this strategy. This is because in reality there are quite a few couplets of rates that I want to do this for consecutively.

EDIT2: Added in some more rows to the example for clarity.

Comment: what about a two step process: first find the uniques where rate1 and rate2 are not NA and then add all the rows where they are both NA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to use `duplicated` on the subset of dataset without the 'Name' column i.e. column index 2 to create a logical vector, negate (`!` - TRUE becomes FALSE and viceversa) so that TRUE would be non-duplicated rows.  Along with that create another condition with `rowSums`on a logical matrix (`is.na(df1[3:4])` - Rate columns) to get rows that are all NA's  - here we compare it with 2 - i.e. the number of Rate columns in the dataset).  Both the conditions are joined by `|` to create the expected logical index

```
i1 <- !duplicated(df1[-2])| rowSums(is.na(df1[3:4])) == 2
df1[i1,]
#    ID Name Rate1 Rate2
#1  1  Xyz     1     2
#3  2  Def    NA    NA
#4  2  Lmn    NA    NA
```

Or with `Reduce` from `base R`

```
df1[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df1[3:4], is.na)) | !duplicated(df1[-2]), ]
```

Wrapping it in a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, i, method ) {     
        
         nm1 <- grep("^Rate", colnames(dat), value = TRUE)    
         i1 <- !duplicated(dat[-i])  
         i2 <-  switch(method, 
           "rowSums" = rowSums(is.na(dat[nm1])) == length(nm1),
           "Reduce" = Reduce(`&`, lapply(dat[nm1], is.na))
         
         )   
         i3 <- i1|i2
         dat[i3,]
     }
```

-testing

```
f1(df1, 2, "rowSums")
#  ID Name Rate1 Rate2
#1  1  Xyz     1     2
#3  2  Def    NA    NA
#4  2  Lmn    NA    NA

f1(df1, 2, "Reduce")
#  ID Name Rate1 Rate2
#1  1  Xyz     1     2
#3  2  Def    NA    NA
#4  2  Lmn    NA    NA

f1(df2, 2, "rowSums")
#  ID Name Rate1 Rate2
#1  1  Xyz     1     2
#3  2  Def    NA    NA
#4  2  Lmn    NA    NA
#5  3  Hij     3     5
#6  3  Qrs     3     7

f1(df2, 2, "Reduce")
#  ID Name Rate1 Rate2
#1  1  Xyz     1     2
#3  2  Def    NA    NA
#4  2  Lmn    NA    NA
#5  3  Hij     3     5
#6  3  Qrs     3     7
```

if there are multiple 'Rate' columns (say 100 or more - only thing to change in the first solution is `2` should be changed to the number of 'Rate' columns)

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyvesrse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter_at(vars(Rate1, Rate2), any_vars(!duplicated(.)|is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID Name  Rate1 Rate2
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
#1     1 Xyz       1     2
#2     2 Def      NA    NA
#3     2 Lmn      NA    NA



df2 %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter_at(vars(Rate1, Rate2), any_vars(!duplicated(.)|is.na(.)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
#     ID Name  Rate1 Rate2
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int>
#1     1 Xyz       1     2
#2     2 Def      NA    NA
#3     2 Lmn      NA    NA
#4     3 Hij       3     5
#5     3 Qrs       3     7
```

---

As @Paul mentioned in the comments, the updated `tidyverse` syntax as on Nov 4 2021 is

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>%
     filter(if_any(cRate1, Rate2), ~ !duplicated(.)|is.na(.)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("Xyz", "Abc", 
"Def", "Lmn"), Rate1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA), Rate2 = c(2L, 2L, NA, 
 NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Name = c("Xyz", 
 "Abc", "Def", "Lmn", "Hij", "Qrs"), Rate1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
 3L, 3L), Rate2 = c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, 5L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I like that tidyverse method the best.

Comment: As `filter_at()` is now superseded, I think the tidyverse syntax would be `filter(across(c(Rate1, Rate2), ~ !duplicated(.) | is.na(.)))`.